# Joining columns in same table

Tags: mysql

I need to get data form table matching the column names and then joining that with the other table using foreign key. 
Here is the table structure:-

Table : **user_master**

```
id |   user_name      |   user_password   |  status
1  |   user_name_1    |       password     |    1
2  |   user_name_2    |       password     |    1
3  |   user_name_3    |       password     |    0
```

Table : **user_meta**

```
id | user_id  |  meta_key  |   meta_value
1  |    1     |   fname    |     kris
2  |    1     |   lname    |     tris
3  |    2     |   fname    |     mac
4  |    2     |   lname    |     book
```

**Is if possible to get results like this ?**

```
id |   user_name       |   user_password   |  status | fname  |  lname
1  |   user_name_1     |   password        |    1    | kris   |  tris
2  |   user_name_2     |   password        |    1    | mac    |  book
```

so that i can use the query and output the data like this

```
    foreach ($rows as $row) { 
        echo $row['id']
        ehco $row['fname'] .... and so on
```

I am using [this library](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) for Database MySQLi query

Can you please help me on this if at all this is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 

id ,   user_name    , user_password  ,status 
(select  meta_value from user_meta um where um.user_id = umst.user_id and meta_key like 'fname') fname  , 
(select  meta_value from user_meta um where um.user_id = umst.user_id and meta_key like 'lname') lname
from 

user_master usmt
```

Comment: this is not helping,  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select meta_value from user_meta um where um.user_id = umst.id ' at line 2`

Answer (score 0):

Use below query this will work for you.

```
SELECT u.id,u.user_name,u.user_password,u.status,
(CASE WHEN um.meta_key = 'fname'  THEN um.meta_value END) as fname,
(SELECT meta_value from user_meta WHERE meta_key = 'lname' AND user_id = u.id ) as lname
FROM `user_master` as u 
INNER JOIN user_meta as um 
ON um.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY id
```